# Account Transaction Method JAVA

Tags: java

I've just started this assignment and I'm in the process of writing my transaction function but I've gone and confused myself.

The instructions are that if a member of the company has started a new transaction and the cashier must input the transaction code and then a payment type:

```
1 - purchase
2 - payment on negative balance
0 - transaction complete (to close out the transaction)
ca - cash payment/purchase
cr - credit payment/purchase.
```

The logic is that the program has to check for the transaction method and then payment type relative to that code before it can do any kind of processing. But Eclipse doesn't like that I'm trying to use an `int` in a boolean check.

I originally had the method as `public double getTransaction()` but I'm thinking that's probably wrong, so I took out the `double` and just left a blank space until I can figure out "type" I should actually be using.

```
private String name; //instance variable that holds the customer's name
    private int accountNumber; //instance variable that holds the customer's account number
    private double transactionCode; //instance variable that holds the account transaction code
    private String paymentType; //instance variable that holds the type of payment for the transaction
    private double beginningBalance; //instance variable that holds the customer's beginning balanceprivate double currentBalance; //instance variable that holds the customer's current account balance
    private double endBalance; //instance variable that holds the customer's end balance after a transaction
    private double creditLimit; //instance variable that holds the limit on the customer's account (per transaction, is what we are going to assume)
    private int numberPurchases; //instance variable that holds the number of purchases made by the customer
    private int numberTransactions; //instance variable that holds the number of transactions made on the customer's account (purchase/payment/denied purchase, etc..)
    private double costOfPurchase; //instance variable that holds the cost of the purchase
    private double totalPurchaseSum; //instance variable that holds the total sum of the customer's purchase
    private double totalPaymentAmount; //instance variable that holds the amount of the payment made by the customer
    private double totalPayments; //instance variable that holds the total number of payments made by the customer
    private double totalPenalty; //instance variable that holds the total amount of the penalty owed to the company by the customer    

//method that gets the type of transaction being processed on the account
        public double getTransaction()
{
    if (transactionCode.equals("1")) //if a purchase is being made
    {
        if (paymentType.equals("ca")) //and if the purchase is being made in cash
            return endBalance = ;
        else if (paymentType.equals("cr")) //else if the purchase is being made in credit
            return creditLimit = getCreditLimit(creditLimit);
    }
    if (transactionCode = 2) //if a payment is being made
    {
        if (paymentType.equals("ca") //and if the payment is being made in cash
            return endBalance = getEndBalance();        
        else if (paymentType.equals("cr")) //else if the payment is being made in credit
    }
    if (transactionCode = 0) //if the current transaction on the account is complete
    {   
        System.out.println("TRANSACTION COMPLETED. THANK YOU FOR YOUR PATRONAGE.")
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: You are doing 2 mistakes. You are using assignment `=` instead of equality `==`. And you shouldn't use `==` to compare `String`, you need to use `.equals()` instead.

Comment: Also your return statements are inconsistent.

Comment: @AleksandrMukhalov Oh thanks! I've fixed it and posted the updated code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what you are asking? What is supposed to be returned from this method? Are you trying to return the end balance? If so, wouldn't it just be zero if the transaction is complete?

Also, there are a few things wrong with your application. First, in the if statements, you are assigning variables, not making comparisons. The equality operator in java is '==', but that is for primitive types. When you are comparing a String (or any Objects) make sure you are using the 'equals' method. Also, there is no need to assign the endBalance variable when returning. You can just return getEndBalance();

Comment: Not necessarily. I'm trying to process two things: A transaction code and a payment type. So the user puts in a transaction value (1, 2, or 0). From there we then have to determine (if code 1 or 2 was input) what type of payment method the customer will be using (cash or credit). Once we have ascertained what type of payment method is to be used, we can process the payment accordingly (ending balance only applies to a credit purchase or payment towards money owed) . If a 0 is entered, we just close out the transaction and return the remaining balance in the account (assuming credit is used).

Comment: So basically: What kind of transaction is this? (user enters 1) Okay, so we're making a purchase. How will that purchase be made? (user enters ca) Okay, so a cash purchase. Let's find out what your total purchase sum is. (program returns the totalPurchaseSum).

Comment: Also, thanks for reminding me about the "=" and "==" thing. It's been awhile since I've done anything Java so my brain kind of reset itself lol

Comment: hmm. So you might want to create a transaction class that holds most of the member variables that you have listed in your code. Then maybe a processTransactionEvent method that handles the transaction input (code, and payment) then modifies the state of your transaction object based on the input. Then you can add other methods to access the state of your trasnaction object. For example, getRemainingBalance, getTransactionStatus.